# Projective system of $C(K)$-spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. The collection $\mathcal{K}$ of all compact subsets of $E$ forms an inductive system of topological spaces by inclusion, i.e. with identity linking mappings $id_{KL} : K \to L$, $x \mapsto x$ for $K, L \in \mathcal{K}$, $K \subseteq L$. Since $E$ is a $k$-space (compactly generated), $E$ is the topological inductive limit of its compact subspaces $\mathcal{K}$. For the spaces of continuous functions we get a projective system by restriction, i.e. with linking mappings $r_{KL} : C(L) \to C(K)$, $f \mapsto f|_K$, $K \subseteq L$. When equipping with the supremum norm (topology), what is the locally convex projective limit of these $C(K)$-spaces? Is it the space $C(E)$ of all continuous functions equipped with the compact-open topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Formally, (a realization of) the projective is the space 
$$
\lim_{\leftarrow} C(K)=\left\{(f_K)_{K\in \mathscr K} \in \prod_{K\in \mathscr K} C(K): r_{KL}(f_L)=f_K \text{ for all } K\subseteq L\right\}
$$
endowed with the relative topology of the product. By local compactness, one gets that $C(E)\to \lim\limits_{\leftarrow} C(K)$, $f\mapsto (f|_K)_{K\in \mathscr K}$ is an isomorphism, if $C(E)$ is endowed with the locally convex topology of uniform convergence on all compact sets.

Comment: What about the general completely regular setup $E$? $C(E)$ with compact-open topology (as with any locally convex space) is a subspace of the product of some Banach spaces. In the non-locally compact setup it may differ from the above projective limit. Is there some interesting characterization of the projective limit in this case?

Comment: The projective limit is the set of functions whose restrictions to compact sets are all continuous -- in general this is not enough for continuity on $E$.

Comment: In the case where $E$ is *compactly generated* (aka known as Kelly spaces) the projective limit is equal to $C(E)$. However, as this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158761/tietzes-extension-theorem-for-compact-subspaces shows, there are cases where the canonical maps $r_{KE}:C(E)\to C(K)$ fail to be surjective although all $r_{KL}$ are surjective.